# Mostrar a data e hora atual (relógio em tempo real)

Tags: javascript, datetime, .net-core

Quero exibir na tela dos sistema a data e hora atual/corrente, que mostre o relógio incrementando os segundos em tempo real.

Já tentei utilizar o `datetime.now` (mostra a data e hora, porém estática, ficando  a hora em que carreguei a página).
`DateTime.today` (só mostra a data). Usei o `DateTime.utcNow` também, mas fica igual o primeiro caso.

**controller:**

```
public IActionResult RegistrarPonto()
        {
            var aux = new RegistroPontoViewModel { DateTime = DateTime.Now };
            return View(aux);
        }
```

**view**

```
    <div>
       <input asp-for="DateTime" type="datetime" class="form-control form-control-lg" readonly />
    </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211145/getting-current-date-and-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você quer fazer não pode ser feito com o `.net`. Você quer um relógio em tempo real então tem que rodar no `client` para o navegador e não no `servidor`. Você até pode recuperar a data atual do seu servidor se for necessário, mas para manter o relógio em tempo real terá que usar `javascript`.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
var timeDisplay = document.getElementById("time");


function refreshTime() {
  var dateString = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Sao_Paulo"});
  var formattedString = dateString.replace(", ", " - ");
  timeDisplay.innerHTML = formattedString;
}

setInterval(refreshTime, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="time"></p>
```

Comment: Obrigado George, funcionou certinho